# Dual Monitor on Arch Linux causes computer to not suspend

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, multi-monitor

I've recently set up a second monitor for my laptop, and for some reason now after I close the lid the computer will just take my external monitor as my primary monitor and not suspend my laptop. I've tried editing my `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` but it doesn't seem to change anything. Can anyone help me out? My DE is Gnome 3.18.2.

`/etc/systemd/logind.conf`:

```
[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
#HandleSuspendKey=suspend
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend
HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#RemoveIPC=yes
#UserTasksMax=4096
```

Comment: Shouldn't `#HandleLidSwitch=suspend` be uncommented?

Comment: I uncommented it but it doesn't affect it at all. If it's just my laptop without the monitor, closing the lid suspends the computer. But once I add the monitor in, it no longer suspends the computer.

Comment: The commented values in logind.conf are showing the default values. You only need to uncomment if you wish to change the value.